# Efficient way to filter out rows which are referenced in other table

Tags: mysql, join

I was wondering if there is a way to filter rows which have a corresponding row in a different table using JOIN operation, or perhaps using any other method which does not involve sub queries.

Here is the only thing I could come up with, however it uses subqueries and I am afraid that it could become quite slow when dealing with very large tables.

```
SELECT * FROM `reports` as R WHERE (
    SELECT COUNT(*) 
    FROM `report_deletes` as RD 
    WHERE 
        RD.report_id = R.id AND
        RD.user_id = 1
) = 0;
```

Comment: I think a poster of this would be awesome: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a left join and check for NULL:

```
SELECT r.* 
FROM reports r 
LEFT JOIN report_deletes rd on r.id = rd.report_id and rd.user_id = 1 
WHERE rd.report_id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use "LEFT JOIN", as below:

```
SELECT *, COUNT(RD.*) as 'count' FROM `reports` as R 
LEFT JOIN `report_deletes` as RD ON (
RD.report_id = R.id )
WHERE 
RD.user_id = 1
AND count = 0
GROUP BY R.id
```